# How do I access OpenCV source compiled package from my Python project venv on windows?

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv

So I have been writing a Python program that utilizes OpenCV for Windows. It's mostly just a project to learn how to use Vision-based Machine Learning. I've gotten the project working with my CPU, and while it "functions" it is abysmally slow, so I wanted to try working with the GPU version instead. Unfortunately, there isn't a python package that has OpenCV with Cuda-enabled GPU functionality (from what I could tell).

So after researching, I found that in order to do what I wanted, I had to compile the OpenCV source code with Cmake. So I set out to do so with the help of [this guide](https://haroonshakeel.medium.com/build-opencv-4-4-0-with-cuda-gpu-support-on-windows-10-without-tears-aa85d470bcd0) which seemed to work (it compiled at least). But now i'm running into the issue of:

I don't actually know how to import this newly built package into my project's venv. I've tried moving the cv2.cp37-win_amd64.pyd into the project's venv site packages, i've tried moving the entire build folder into the project and directly importing it, but neither actually worked... so I'm a little at a loss on what to do to get OpenCV with GPU enabled CUDA working in my project.

EDIT:

I followed the guide that Miki linked, including installing Anaconda and all that jazz. The package imports correctly when I use:

Following @Miki's suggestion, I went through the guide that they linked, following all of the processes, testing that OpenCV was in fact being built correctly with:

```
 set path=%openCvBuild%\install\x64\vc16\bin;%path%
 python -c "import cv2; print(f'OpenCV: {cv2.__version__} for python installed and working')"
```

But it still isn't showing up in the python import in conda, despite being in the env's site-packages folder.

Comment: see [here](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/07/11/compiling-opencv-with-cuda-support/), in particular: _"Note: You’ll want to find and make note of where your cv2.so file is on your system! Whenever we create a virtual environment (which we’ll be doing lots of to explore various deep learning libraries), you’ll want to sym-link the cv2.so file into the site-packages directory of your Python virtual environment so you have access to OpenCV."_

Comment: @Miki hmmm I don't seem to have a cv2.so file in the build folder... maybe it's elsewhere on the system? I'll keep looking. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: [check here](https://jamesbowley.co.uk/accelerate-opencv-4-4-0-build-with-cuda-and-python-bindings/), you should be looking for something called similar to cv2.cp37-win_amd64.pyd in the site-packages dir (probably of your default python installation)

Comment: Edited my post to include the comment with the code formatted